# Ionic angular won't send headers

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to store data in database with API and I'm getting `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object` error.

The reason that I'm getting that error is because Ionic won't send my user token to server

```
0: Closure (HttpHeaders)
  headers:
    Accept: "application/json, text/plain"
    Authorization: "undefined undefined"  <--- here
    Content-Type: "application/json"
```

## Code

`store.page.ts`

This data will send to store services and from there to the server.

```
create() {
    const addToko = this.addToko.value;
    this.storeService.store(
      addToko.name,
      addToko.description,
      addToko.phone,
      addToko.province_id,
      addToko.kota_id,
      addToko.address,
      addToko.logo = this.logoURI,
      addToko.banner = this.bannerURI,
    ).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.alertService.presentToast(data);
        console.log('done ', data);
      },
      error => {
        this.alertService.presentToast(error);
        console.log('error ', error);
      }
    );
  }
```

`store.service.ts`

Data from here will send to server

```
export class StoreService {

  token: any; //setting user token

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private env: EnvService,
    private storage: NativeStorage,
  ) {
   //gettinguser token
    this.storage.getItem('token').then(
      data => {
        this.token = data;
        console.log('token data', data);
      },
      error => {
        this.token = null;
      }
    );
  }

  store(
    name: String,
    description: String,
    phone: String,
    province_id: String,
    kota_id: String,
    address: String,
    logo: String,
    banner: String,
  ) {
    // adding headers to request
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': this.token["token_type"] + " " + this.token["access_token"]
    });

    return this.http.post(this.env.STORES_URL,
      { name: name, description: description, phone: phone, province_id: province_id, kota_id: kota_id, address: address, logo: logo, banner: banner, headers: headers } // defining headers to request
    )
  }
}
```

**Might be a bit of help:**

I have `Auth.service.ts` which takes care of user loggin status and route guards etc. there I have function below which gets users token and in there it's working just fine, I implemented same function in my `store.service.ts (code above)` but it doesn't work.

```
getToken() {
    return this.storage.getItem('token').then(
      data => {
        this.token = data;
        if (this.token != null) {
          this.isLoggedIn = true;
        } else {
          this.isLoggedIn = false;
        }
      },
      error => {
        this.token = null;
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
      }
    );
  }
```

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 0):

your implemenation of `store` service needs a correction. 
You've included the `headers` in object body, take it out from there.

```
    return this.http.post(this.env.STORES_URL,
           { name: name, description: description, phone: phone, province_id: 
             province_id, kota_id: kota_id, address: address, logo: logo, 
             banner: banner, headers: headers /* headers should not be embedded in object body*/
           });

    return this.http.post(this.env.STORES_URL,
           { name: name, description: description, phone: phone, province_id: 
             province_id, kota_id: kota_id, address: address, logo: logo, 
             banner: banner
           }, {headers: headers});
```

Comment: then you might want to try putting a debugger anc check the value of `this.token["token_type"] + " " + this.token["access_token"]`

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a race condition, the token has not been set before making the request. You could make a **[http-interceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses)** to take care of setting the auth header to your requests:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest
} from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { of, from} from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class NoopInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):
    Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    // convert promise to observable
    // fetch token and switch to inner observable where we add headers
    return from(this.storage.getItem('token')).pipe(
      switchMap((token) => {
        // clone request and add headers
        const authReq = req.clone({
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Authorization': token["token_type"] + " " + token["access_token"]
          })
        })
        return next.handle(authReq);
      })
    )
}
```

Add the interceptor to `providers` array in app.module:

```
{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: NoopInterceptor, multi: true },
```

Then just remove the `httpOptions` from your request (which was like in other answer, in the wrong place):

```
return this.http.post(this.env.STORES_URL,
       { name: name, description: description, phone: phone, province_id: 
         province_id, kota_id: kota_id, address: address, logo: logo, 
         banner: banner
       });
```

Comment: so this will share my user token in all pages and i should remove headerOptions from all my requests in all pages or....?

Comment: Yes, that would be the case. This works only though when the token has been set before any http-requests are made. I assume that this is a race condition where your http-request is called before `this.token` has been set in the service. If this doesn't help, please create a [mcve] on how and when you get the token etc.